# Azerothcore: Looping on Realm Selection List

Tags: azerothcore

I've set up Azerothcore for a friend. In attempting to access the server I get stuck at the Realm Selection list.

```
Worldserver conf extract:
LoginDatabaseInfo     = "127.0.0.1;3306;acore;acore;acore_auth"
WorldDatabaseInfo     = "127.0.0.1;3306;acore;acore;acore_world"
CharacterDatabaseInfo = "127.0.0.1;3306;acore;acore;acore_characters"

Authserver conf extract:
LoginDatabaseInfo = "127.0.0.1;3306;acore;acore;acore_auth"


SQLDatabase:
acore_auth/realmlist
address: 127.0.0.1
localaddress: 127.0.0.1
port: 8085
```

I built the same server on my own PC without any issue. I can connect to his server using his external IP and I can log in fine using the account I created in the worldserver console, but when I click on the "Azerothcore" realm listed in the Realm Selection list it briefly says "Logging in to game server" briefly before looping around to the same Realm Selection list.

Any help anyone could offer would be much appreciated. Thanks.

We've both been looking through other similar issues for other emulators but none of the fixes proposed for those apply to Azerothcore.

Answer (score 2):

In the SQL acore_auth database realm list table the external address was still set to 127.0.0.1. Oddly I had **absolutely** changed this, but it didn't seem to stick, when my friend changed it again, the server worked and performed normally.

Comment: In case of doubt, checking for networking is good since It's usually the first barrier

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this issue as well. I finally figured out that heidi initially opens the table in the tables tab, which can't edit persistently. Heidi will appear to do the edit. every time you open the table in heidi it will look edited, but if you open the table in comandline or sql work bench, the Database contains only the default values. The solution is to open the table in heidi then click the "Data" tab. Here, you can perform actual edits.