# AzerothCore - still looping to realm selection even after updating IP address (Docker install)

Tags: azerothcore, world-of-warcraft

I have followed the guides at https://www.azerothcore.org/acore-docker/, and everything installs and works fine. Auth, WorldServer, DB, etc all work.  However, when trying to play locally (LAN, main computer with client, the server on a different Windows machine on same LAN), it consistently loops back to realm selection.

So, I searched here and found these two questions/answers:
[Azerothcore: Looping on Realm Selection List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68081167/azerothcore-looping-on-realm-selection-list)
[How to resolve sticking in "Realm Selection"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54852245/how-to-resolve-sticking-in-realm-selection)

I have followed the guide in the bottom one, and have changed the Address field in the database to my external IP address (assigned by ISP). The `LocalAddress` is `127.0.0.1` The rest of the information appears to be correct.

When trying to connect via the external IP, it won't connect at all. But when I try setting my realmlist to `127.0.0.1` it will connect and log me in, but continually loops back to the realm selection screen.

To make sure it was updating, I changed the name of the realm and it shows up correctly when I try and log in. So the data appears to be saved to the database, but I cannot get it to connect from the LAN.

Followed the official guides, and changed the IP address in the DB to external IP. Same result, except now it takes a few seconds to connect and try to log into the realm. Then fails, back to realm selection.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 99.9% related to your networking. That's what it turns out to be for pretty much everyone asking this question.

Most likely either a port isn't forwarded correctly, or your firewall prevents the connection. Try and use an external service to verify if the port is open. (Do a search for "Port open check"). Also, check your firewall to have the worldserver listed as an exception in the right folder.

Another common mistake is to change the "default" values when using HeidiSQL in the realmlist db instead of changing the actual values in the 'data' tab.

Comment: Yep, that was it. The port forward wasn't configured properly. Using Unifi UXG Pro, I had to go in there and check the WAN1 port IP. For some reason, that's different than my public IP. Weird. Put that in as address, and it works perfectly. Thank you!